# Should I use pairwise Mahalanobis distances or Euclidean distances?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, distance

I have the historic values of economic variables at quarter-ends for around 120 quarters. I wish to quantify how different the economy is at any two given point in time in my dataset (i.e. to produce 120x119 distances).

Should I use euclidean distance on scaled data, or would the Mahalanobis distance (between each pair of points) be a more appropriate measure of distance? In other words, does it make sense to make the adjustment to the euclidean distance between scaled points to take into account covariance between variables, as the Mahalobis distance effectively does?

The mahalanobis distance between vectors x and y is defined as
$$
[(x-y)'C^{-1}(x-y)]^{1/2}
$$

where C is the sample covariance matrix.

I'm not interested in classifying points into clusters or groups of any kind. I just want to quantitatively express how different each point in time is to every other point in time.

Would Mahalanobis distance be an improvement on euclidean distance in this setting?

Comment: I guess I am having a problem with what the Mahalanobis distance between two points even means.  I can sort of grasp the distance between  a point and a distribution (e,g, a large distance means you have an outlier), but what exactly the Mahalanobis distance between two points means is proving more elusive to me.

Comment: One way to think of Mahalanobis distance is by contours of a bivariate Gaussian. If the distribution is isotropic (i.e. radially symmetric), then these contours will be circles. If there is a difference in variance (spread) between $x$ and $y$, of a covariance between the two, then the contours will be ellipses (rotated in the covariance case). In any case, all points on a contour have equal *Mahalanobis* distance to the origin. Once you take the difference between two of your points, the offset vector is then comparable to a point in this space.